# Slightly move x- or y-axis tick label in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning

In the MWE below, I'd like to move the x-axis labels *slightly* away from each other horizontally and the y-axis labels *slightly* away from each other vertically, to avoid overlapping. How can I do this?

[image]

I tried adding a `\quad` to the first `extra x tick label`, which more or less worked, but it seems inelegant, and it doesn't work for the y-axis.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \newcommand\CONSTH{326.4887}
    \newcommand\CONSTS{205.0669}
    \newcommand\CONSTgS{193.1713}   
    \newcommand\CONSTHd{300}        
    \newcommand\CONSTmu{200}    

    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        scaled ticks=false,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xmin=165,
        xmax=250,
        ymin=0,
        extra x ticks={\CONSTmu, \CONSTS}, 
        extra x tick labels={$\lambda L$, $S^*$},
        extra y ticks={\CONSTH, \CONSTHd},
        extra y tick labels={$H(Q)$, $H_d(Q)$}
    ]

    \addplot[ticks=none] coordinates {(170,400) (\CONSTmu,0) (245,400)};
    \addplot[ticks=none,domain=170:245] {0.1*(x-\CONSTS)^2 + \CONSTgS}; 

    % x axis labels
    \addplot[dashed]
    coordinates {(\CONSTS,0) (\CONSTS,\CONSTgS)};

    % y axis labels
    \addplot[dashed]
    coordinates {(0,\CONSTH) (245,\CONSTH)};
    \addplot[dashed]
    coordinates {(0,\CONSTHd) (245,\CONSTHd)};

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*Edit:* Replaced data from tables with formulas.

Comment: We can not get the picture due to  the absence of tables `gy.dat` and `gdy.dat`,  try to reduce the size of tick labels with `tick label style={font=\scriptsize}`.

Comment: I edited to remove the .dat files -- thanks for that. Same question still applies. I don't really want to change the font size since then this figure won't match the other figures in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox` to  move box containing y tick label, for x tick label you can use as you  mentioned `\quad` or moving the two x tick label with `\kern`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \newcommand\CONSTH{326.4887}
    \newcommand\CONSTS{205.0669}
    \newcommand\CONSTgS{193.1713}   
    \newcommand\CONSTHd{300}        
    \newcommand\CONSTmu{200}    

    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        scaled ticks=false,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xmin=165,
        xmax=250,
        ymin=0,
        extra x ticks={\CONSTmu, \CONSTS}, 
        extra x tick labels={\kern-1mm $\lambda L$,\kern1mm $S^*$},
        extra y ticks={\CONSTH, \CONSTHd},
        extra y tick labels={\raisebox{2mm}{$H(Q)$},\raisebox{-3mm}{$H_d(Q)$}},
        ]

    \addplot[ticks=none] coordinates {(170,400) (\CONSTmu,0) (245,400)};
    \addplot[ticks=none,domain=170:245] {0.1*(x-\CONSTS)^2 + \CONSTgS}; 

    % x axis labels
    \addplot[dashed]
    coordinates {(\CONSTS,0) (\CONSTS,\CONSTgS)};

    % y axis labels
    \addplot[dashed]
    coordinates {(0,\CONSTH) (245,\CONSTH)};
    \addplot[dashed]
    coordinates {(0,\CONSTHd) (245,\CONSTHd)};

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: It's better to hide the height and depth, as in  `extra y tick labels={\raisebox{1mm}[0pt][0pt]{$H(Q)$},\raisebox{-2mm}[0pt][0pt]{$H_d(Q)$}}`.